# Add Comma after Every 11 Digits in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I want to pus comma after every 11 digits in excel my data will be like this.

`ODU88131042ODU88131043ODU88131044ODU88131045ODU65110840ODU65110829ODU65110833ODU65110834ODU88131046ODU88131047ODU88131048ODU88131049ODU88131`

and i want answer like this

```
ODU88131046,ODU88131047,ODU88131048,ODU88131049,ODU88131050,ODU88131051,ODU88131052,ODU88131053,ODU88131054,ODU88131055,ODU88131056,ODU88131057,ODU88131058,ODU88131059,ODU88131060,ODU88131061,ODU88131062,ODU88131063,ODU88131064,ODU88131065,ODU88131066,ODU88131067,ODU88131068,ODU88131069,ODU88131070,ODU88131071,ODU88131072,ODU88131073,ODU88131074,ODU88131075,ODU88131076,ODU88131077,ODU88131078,ODU88131079,ODU88131080,ODU88131081,ODU88131082,ODU88131083,ODU88131084,ODU88131085,ODU88131086,ODU88131087,ODU88131088,ODU88131089,ODU88131090,
```

its a fix that i want comma in very 11 digits and the row it in only one cell and result is also shows in one cell only. please help me out..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a method using VBA. Select the cell you want to put commas in and run the macro.

```
Sub AddCommas()
    Dim s As String
    s = Selection.Value
    Dim x As Long
    x = Len(s) \ 11
    If Len(s) Mod 11 = 0 Then
        x = x - 1
    End If
    Do Until x <= 0
        s = Left(s, x * 11) & "," & Mid(s, x * 11 + 1)
        x = x - 1
    Loop
    Selection.Value = s
End Sub
```

Comment: @pnuts Indeed, especially since you'll have to keep expanding it the longer the string gets. I assumed that someone would provide a formula based solution, but VBA seemed more reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(" "&SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,REPT("00000000000 ",EVEN(LEN(C4)))),"00000000000 ",)," 00000000000 ",))," ",",")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.